# Sorting a list of tuples by the sum of elements in inner lists

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I am attempting to produce a function that returns a sorted list of the sum of the respective numbers in the list>tuple>list combination. Example:

```
unsorted_list = [('red', [5, 2, 1]), ('blue', [1, 0, 1]), ('green', [2, 3, 2])]
```

The program needs to look at the numbers in the list, add them (8,2,7), then order the numbers so that the sorted list is the same format as the unsorted list, but ordered by the sum of the numbers.

To produce a list like this:

```
sorted_list = [('blue', [1, 0, 1]), ('green', [2, 3, 2]), ('red', [5, 2, 1])]
```

Notice how the numbers themselves don't change order - this is a key requirement, as it relates to co-ordinates. Just the order of the list elements based on the sum of the numbers.

Comment: This is basically the same as [Python, how to sort a list based on a sum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40351341/364696), just with a slightly different `key` function.

Comment: I couldn't find that post, but would have also helped me solve the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort using a `lambda` function as the key. This lambda function returns the sum of the list element of the tuples in your unsorted list:

```
>>> sorted(unsorted_list, key=lambda x: sum(x[1]))
[('blue', [1, 0, 1]), ('green', [2, 3, 2]), ('red', [5, 2, 1])]
```